# PC makes constant loud clicking sound after 30 minutes of sleep

Tags: power-supply, sleep, clicking-sound, intel-nuc

Summary: Newbuild PC makes clicking sounds after 30 minutes of sleep.

Newbuild Intel Nuc Extreme 13. Works perfectly, however after 30 minutes of sleep it starts making loud ticking sound. It seems that for the first 30 minutes, Windows holds most of the PC on/active in sleep mode, but after 30 minutes it shuts off the graphics card too. At this point, a ticking sound starts, I'm 90% sure it's the PSU shutting on and off.

I tried replacing the cable, connecting to a different outlet, removing all devices and connections. I haven't yet tried removing the GPU completely, but I can do that.
I made a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_3GGD6qt04 to show the problem. As you see, removing the USB devices temporarily wakes it up, but after a few seconds it goes back to sleep and the clicking sound starts again.

Any ideas, or next steps to diagnose it?

Comment: Can you remove the side or cover and hear more clearly what is making the noise?

Comment: I removed everything and as far as I can guess it's coming from the PSU. At the point that it's making sounds, nothing else is running (no fans, etc) so I'm pretty sure it's coming from that

Comment: Can the PSU be returned (warranty) ?   Little power used when hibernated

Comment: @John I've RMA'ed the entire NUC body. Still in warranty as 5 days old. Will post the result as an answer